# Dependent chi-squares vector: how to calculate cdf of $X_{(n)}$?

Tags: chi-squared-test, cumulative-distribution-function, independence

Consider a vector of central&1-degree Chi square distributed variable $(X_1, X_2,...,X_n)$, it is simple to calculate the cdf of $X_{(n)}$ (maximum of order statistics), when they are independent. What will be the solution if they are dependent? Assume the correlation matrix is $C$. Is there at least some fast&precise numerical approximation?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the correlation between chi-square random variables doesn't determine their dependence structure (nor indeed, is it the case in general that specifying correlation determines a multivariate distribution).

Hence $X_{(n)}$ is not determined by the conditions you have specified.

A caution though -- in general, in the absence of independence, such calculations are often quite difficult.

Once things are sufficiently specified, I'd generally rely on simulation.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, I realize that the dependence structure is not fully determined by the correlation structure, unlike that in the multivariate normal case.